# How do i know if example.com is delegating example.mydomain.com to its own zone?

Tags: domain-name-system, delegation

An additional question is, can I find out what zones `example.com` is delegating to?

This all assumes I am not an Admin for any of the sites/zones in question -- I'm just on the public internet, these are public-facing servers/zones, etc.

If i know that `foo.example.com` exists, and it has an SOA record, does that mean that it is being delegated to, by definition? (assuming it's not configured incorrectly)

so if I query a domain for NS records, and they show up, then, by definition, those are the authoritative name servers for that domain?

`me@WIN-0G109DMKIEK:~$ dig NS example.com +short b.iana-servers.net. a.iana-servers.net.`

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a delegation means `NS` records.

So check if `foo.example.com` has NS records on authoritative nameservers for `example.com`.

The `NS` records will show, if there, the authoritative nameservers for the subdomain.

This works the same way at all level of the DNS tree, here showing the delegation from `com` to `example.com`:

```
$ dig NS @$(dig NS com +short | head -1) example.com +noall +auth
example.com.        2d IN NS a.iana-servers.net.
example.com.        2d IN NS b.iana-servers.net.
```

> If i know that foo.example.com exists, and it has an SOA record, does that mean that it is being delegated to, by definition? (assuming it's not configured incorrectly)

The SOA in the child is technically also a proof of delegation, normally. To be 100% correct you need more than that to check the delegation point or cut zone case, at the parent, and if it has `NS` records.

Comment: so if I query a domain for NS records, and they show up, then, by definition, those are the authoritative name servers for that domain?

`me@WIN-0G109DMKIEK:~$ dig NS example.com +short
b.iana-servers.net.
a.iana-servers.net.`

Comment: You need to ask the authoritative servers where you think the delegation happens, so you need the `@` option, see my example. But the `NS` records are designing who are the authoritative nameservers for that delegation, yes.